# Need help identifying a curve

Tags: regression, curve-fitting

I have a data which I'm trying to fit a curve to. The data looks like this:
[image: data]

At the first glance, the dependency is linear, so I should just use linear regression and end up with this:
[image]

But then, I think, something like this would fit a bit better:
[image]
(this is hand-drawn)

So my question is: does a curve of such shape have a name? Is there some known parametric equation that I could toy with to achieve what I want?
[image]

Comment: If you fit a cubic polynomial, are the non-linear terms significant?

Comment: @Estacionario, I'm sorry, I'm not really sure what you're asking. I'll look into cubic polynomial curves

Comment: The curve you drew is visibly a worse fit than the line: at each extreme, most of the points above or below the curve lie on one side of it.

Comment: What do the residuals say? Sum them up for both linear and cubic polynomial regression & see.

Comment: I extracted data from the scatterplot for analysis, and found only a very tiny difference in using cubic and linear polynomials. I think the reason for this is the relatively large amount of data in the central region is not allowing any curvature there, forcing the polynomial into what is essentially a straight line regardless of polynomial order. Lower order polynomials cannot simultaneously be both straight in this region and curved outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, hand drawn curves don't have names. But what you have drawn looks close to a cubic polynomial.

If you are trying to fit a curve to your data and want to do something computer drawn rather than hand drawn, you could investigate splines, such as restricted cubic splines.

Comment: I'm fitting my curves in Python, I've hand drawn this just to show what I'm striving to achieve. Thanks, I will look into cubic polynomial curves.